# I'm having error Cannot assign value of type

Tags: swift, decode

Why I'm error:  Cannot assign value of type 'Clause' to type 'Clause.Type'

Clause.Swift file

```
struct Clause: Codable {
 var Id: Int
 var ClauseNo: String
}
```

MainViewController.swift file

```
var clause = Clause.self

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
      parse(json: data)
    }
  }
}

func parse(json: Data) {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  if let jsonClause = try? decoder.decode(Clause.self, from: json) {

      clause = jsonClause  //<===== Error on this line
      print(jsonClause)
}
}
```

Comment: `var clause: Clause?`

Comment: start property names wit small letters and use ` try-catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
var clause = Clause.self
```

with either

```
var clause:Clause?
```

or

```
var clause:Clause!
```

Having `Clause.self` here

```
decoder.decode(Clause.self, from: json)
```

doen't mean you need a var of that type , the return of the decoder is an instance of `Clause`

---

Don't use

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
```

as it blocks the main thread , consider using **Alamofire**/**URLSession**